# heroku hosting apython flask application error

Tags: python, heroku, flask, hosting

i have recently deployed my python flask app to heroku but the following error occurs:

```
2016-07-29T17:32:00.145010+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-07-29T17:32:11.162187+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn myapp:app --log-file=-`
2016-07-29T17:32:13.548294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2016-07-29T17:32:13.448537+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-29 17:32:13 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
2016-07-29T17:32:13.449154+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-29 17:32:13 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:57535 (3)
2016-07-29T17:32:13.456988+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2016-07-29T17:32:13.456990+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-07-29T17:32:13.456993+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/myapp.py", line 71
2016-07-29T17:32:13.456994+00:00 app[web.1]:     data[i]={**a[i],**b,**c,**d,**e}
2016-07-29T17:32:13.563973+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-29T17:32:14.847126+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-plateau-26852.herokuapp.com request_id=820cdbd3-d478-434b-be65-06f959ca2798 fwd="79.167.50.52" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-07-29T17:32:14.370705+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-plateau-26852.herokuapp.com request_id=48a7f184-053b-4ba9-9833-a5e27df61867 fwd="79.167.50.52" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

i have tried changing the default ports etc. but the same error occurs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your project and app actually called `myapp` and `app`?

Comment: the python script that i run is called myapp.py thus i defined it as my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is in the traceback. Error code  `H10` means the app crashed when Gunicorn tried to load it onto the dyno.  There's an error at line 71 of your `myapp.py file`, the `data[i]={**a[i],**b,**c,**d,**e}` line.   You may need to show the rest of your file to debug that.

Comment: i actually do not get any errors when running this code locally..
thus can it be a related issue on the cloud?

Comment: Sure.  But it'll be impossible to tell if you don't put a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question up.

Comment: the error was that the default python version was 2.7.12 and the respective command is not valid for this version. Thus i added a runtime.txt. file with the line :python-3.5.2